# How to read a line which include spaces in the end from Console in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, stdin

I try to get stdin from readLine() in Swift, but the following two string to become the same one, but they should be different, while the latter one got more space.

```
//Console
abcd
abcd    
//

let a = readline()!
let b = readline()!
print(a==b)
```

The second line from stdin got four more space in the end.

Is there any Swift api to solve this problem?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this – the two strings entered always compare false for me, which I would expect. [Looking at the source](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/InputStream.swift#L42), `strippingNewline` only removes combinations of newline feeds (`\n`) and carriage returns (`\r`). Also you meant `readLine()` instead of `readline()`, right?

Comment: I think I should pause my question.
The input came from a textfield on a online coding test editor, so the output may be preprocessed by the webpage and will be different from Xcode.